# Cannot solve "Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml" because filename has repository id appended during Maven download

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin

**How do I configure in Maven resp. in IntelliJ, that the id "d-central" is not appended to the "maven-metadata.xml" filename, or other way round, that Maven accepts "maven-metadata-d-central.xml" as the file name for plugins?**

I'm using a fresh IntelliJ 2021.3.3 and re-imported a multi-module Maven 3/ Spring 2 project from our Git repository `https://devtools/artifactory/repos/`

Maven downloads all artifacts into the local ....m2\respository

Maven settings are located at the correct location `C:\Users\kitekat\.m2\settings.xml` and, as I tested by changing and letting them be reloaded, are correctly read by Maven. These are the settings:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>d-central</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>https://devtools/artifactory/repos</url>
    <name>Artifactory</name>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>


<profiles>
  </profile>
    <id>default_profile</id>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>d-central</id>
        <name>extra Plugin Repo</name>
        <url>https://devtools/artifactory/repos</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

I can install all application modules using `mvn install -f pom.xml` but I cannot start the Spring application like I did earlier by running

```
mvn spring-boot:run -e -X -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=myProfile -f pom.xml
```

Maven complains:

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\kitekat\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\kitekat\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\kitekat\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\kitekat\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://devtools/artifactory/repos
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://devtools/artifactory/repos
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://devtools/artifactory/repos
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://devtools/artifactory/repos
Downloading from d-central: https://devtools/artifactory/repos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from d-central: https://devtools/artifactory/repos/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from d-central: https://devtools/artifactory/repos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (11 kB at 4.9 kB/s)
Downloaded from d-central: https://devtools/artifactory/repos/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 8.9 kB/s)
```

Looking into the mentioned directories, I see the newly downloaded "maven-metadata.xml" files in place:

C:\Users\kitekat.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-d-central.xml
C:\Users\kitekat.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-metadata-d-central.xml

But: as is obvious, the file names are appendend the id "d-central" of the settings.xml settings during download by Maven.

As a result, the Spring Boot plugin is not found in the local repository:

"[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\kitekat.m2\repository), d-central (https://devtools/artifactory/repos)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\kitekat.m2\repository), d-central (https://devtools/artifactory/repos)]"

Comment: Can you please show the full pom file...

Comment: Thanks to your input, @khmarbaise, I could figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve the issue during replying to @khmarbaise: accidentally, a wrong working directory had been entered in setting up the experimental Run/Debug Configuration. Corrected it to "dsp-portal" and could then start the application.

See image
[image]

Obviously, the appendend "d-central" from the settings.xml id is a correct behavior and didn't stop the Spring Boot application from starting up, but when the working directory isn't set correctly, Maven searches in the wrong directory.